# Convolutional neural network using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, deep-learning

I wonder if there is a way of building a convolutional neural network with openCV. Basically I have already trained the cifarnet cnn using the python API of Tensorflow but now I want to run the inference without tensorflow by using C++. The only open-source lib that I can use is opencv. Do you know if I can do that with opencv instead of creating the network manually?

Comment: TensorFlow has a C++ API, there is no need to use OpenCV.

Comment: I know but the only 3rd party open-source lib that I can use for inference is opencv. I could use tensorflow only for training.

Comment: Then its better to do everything with OpenCV, as it doesn't support the same features as TensorFlow.

Comment: Ok so probably I can use the dnn lib to build it. The next step will be to restore the weights from the .ckpt tensorflow file. It is maybe a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at deep learning module from [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). Some sample with evaluating model trained in TensorFlow in dnn/samples/tf_inception.cpp. Also some hints about making snapshot in issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1029#issuecomment-290070240.